# Simple probabilistic expression

Tags: problem-solving

For the following expression:

$$
 \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{2n-i}{3n-i} 
$$

I'm trying to get a simple expression, unsuccessfully.

Many thanks, Jonathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{2n-i}{3n-i}&=\frac{\frac{(2n)!}{n!}}{\frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!}}\\\\
&=\frac{\binom{2n}nn!}{\binom{3n}nn!}\\\\
&=\frac{\binom{2n}n}{\binom{3n}n}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Of course you can replace the denominator with $\binom{3n}{2n}$ if you prefer. I doubt that you can get much nicer than this, though you can use [Stirling’s approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to get an estimate for large $n$.

Comment: @Jonathan: You’re welcome.